# Angular HTTP POST Request throwing net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR error

Tags: angular, post, http-headers, slim

I have my own API and a `POST` route working as follows,

**`Server`**

```
//  Handling CORS with a simple lazy CORS
$app->options('/{routes:.+}', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    return $response;
});
$app->add(function ($req, $res, $next) {
    $response = $next($req, $res);
    return $response
        ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Origin, Authorization, application/json')
        ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST')
        ->withHeader('Content-Type','application/json')
        ->withHeader('X-Powered-By','Mercurial API');

});

...

$app->post('/api/log', function( Request $request, Response $response){
    
    $category = $request->getParam('category');
    $value = $request->getParam('value');
     
    return logQuery($category, $value, $response);

});
```

When i am sending a HTTP POST Request from other sources the server is responding fine, [Kindly click here to see the example](https://www.apirequest.io/5dbaaa08717bd47fa5ab4804?at=eyJhcHAiOiI1ZGJhYWEwODcxN2JkNDdmYTVhYjQ4MDQiLCJhdWQiOiI2dVowbk9qZnJyOE5JajRyOEk2Tk51clN2RjdWWTJtTCIsInZlciI6IjEiLCJvcmciOiIwOjAiLCJwZXJtaXNzaW9ucyI6eyIwOjAiOnsic2NwIjoiY3JlYXRlOndvcmtzcGFjZXMgcmVhZDp3b3Jrc3BhY2VzIHVwZGF0ZTp3b3Jrc3BhY2VzIGRlbGV0ZTp3b3Jrc3BhY2VzIn19LCJleHAiOjE1NzUwNzIwMDAsImp0aSI6ImYyZTMyYzdhLWZlNjctNGQ5NC05N2FkLTM5ODE1NWU2MTc2ZCJ9.6fUu07dca3uQ8dlwAekvfB6G-6v-VGnwsscBVaSGsN0)

> category:"SOME CAT"
>
> value:"SOME VAL"

But when i sending the same through my Angular App,

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type':'application/json'
  })
};

...

  public putLog(category: string, value: string) {
    //  You can add new argument in header like,
    //  httpOptions.headers = httpOptions.headers.set('Authorization', 'my-new-auth-token');

    const body = JSON.stringify({ category: category, value: value });

    console.log(body);
    return this.http.post<any>(this.apiUrl + '/log', body, httpOptions)
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          console.log('PUT Request is successful.');
        },
        (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          if (err.error instanceof Error) {
            console.log('Client-side error occured.');
          } else {
            console.log('Server-side error occured.');
          }
        });

    }
  }
```

i am getting the following error.

```
{"category":"message","value":"asdasd"}
Server-side error occured.
OPTIONS https://sizilkrishna.000webhostapp.com/api/public/api/log net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your api expects HttpParams, so you should set your params as params and not body:

```ts
const params = new HttpParams().set("category", category).set("value", value);

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Accept': 'application/json',
  }),
  params: params
};
```

and then have body as `null`:

```ts
return this.http
  .post<any>(
    this.apiUrl + "/log",
    null,
    httpOptions
  )
  // .....
```

That seems to work just fine: **[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nprgv5?file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

Comment: Thanks, It worked. But how would i combine httpOptions along with the queryParams?

Comment: Updated my answer with sample with `Accept`, since you cannot add header `'Content-Type':'application/json'` as that is not what you send :)

Comment: True, but originally i was using `PUT` request, i rolled back to `POST` for debugging. Now with your solution i can go back to implementing my original code! Thanks again. :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you missing the request params in your post request?

{params: {categogy: '2', message: .., ...}}

because when I use your link with request params, I get a 200 result. but you are not sending request params to your backend.

send request params with angular or expect a request body in your backend. but I am not familiar with node/express. but it seems like thats whats going wrong.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, at first i thought that too and changed my function to `return this.http.post<any>(this.apiUrl + '/log',{
      params: new HttpParams()
        .set('category', category)
        .set('value', value)
    } )` , but still the same error.

Comment: I would like to add that your solution was correct the fault lied in my implementation, sorry about that.

Comment: its running now, thats all that counts :D

Answer (score 1):

After searching for few hours finally got a solution
my issue was when i pass headers to http get or post requests i got the ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR error
i see the issue only if i use angular http and the api works perfect on postman or other online http post tools with headers.

the solution i made is to go to your server side php file (api file)
and make sure its only returning a single echo no more than one and check if there is any issue need to be fixed.

this is my code

```
import { HttpClient , HttpParams, HttpHeaders, HttpErrorResponse} from '@angular/common/http';

  const httpOptions = {
     headers: new HttpHeaders({
     'Content-Type':  'application/json',
     Authorization: 'Your-Api-Key'
   })
   };

   console.log(httpOptions)

   return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/api.php',httpOptions).subscribe((data)=>{
        console.log(data)
    })
```