# Angular HttpErrorResponse net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Tags: angular, http

hello I'm trying to build authentication i have  a sign up and login form , the backend built with Laravel ,Rest APIs works correctly with Postman so the problem almost is from the angular app
when i'm trying to send a request i get this error

> POST https://masterytest.000webhostapp.com/public/api/Login polyfills.js:3156 net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR
>
> HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText:
> "Unknown Error", url:
> "https://masterytest.000webhostapp.com/public/api/Login", ok: false,
> …} error: ProgressEvent {isTrusted: true, lengthComputable: false,
> loaded: 0, total: 0, type: "error", …} headers: HttpHeaders message:
> "Http failure response for
> https://masterytest.000webhostapp.com/public/api/Login: 0 Unknown
> Error"

I'm hosting my Laravel project on 000webhost

I use and interceptor to attach a token to every request and user Id to every ongoing request except the signup

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
return this.authService.newUser.pipe(
  take(1),
  exhaustMap(user => {
    if (!user) {
        req.clone({
          headers: new HttpHeaders({
            Authorization: '',
            User_ID:'',
          })
      });
      return next.handle(req);
    }
    const modifiedReq = req.clone({
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        Authorization: user.token,
        User_ID:user.User_ID,
      })
    });
    return next.handle(modifiedReq);
  })
);};
```

and I have an Authservice ,I store the user in  this new user and this is my log in

```
newUser = new BehaviorSubject<User>(null);
    userLogin(nameEmail: string, password: string) {
        return this.http
          .post<AuthResponseData>(
            'https://masterytest.000webhostapp.com/public/api/Login',
            {
              Secret_Key:"******",
              nameEmail :nameEmail ,
              password : password
            }
          )
          .pipe(
            //catchError(this.handleError),
            tap((resData) => {
              this.handleUserAuth(
                resData.User_ID,
                resData.User_Token,
                resData.User_Type,
                resData.User_Name
              );
            })
          );
      }
```

then I subscribe in the log in component

Comment: Please check this Q&A : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58640844/angular-http-post-request-throwing-neterr-http2-protocol-error-error

Comment: Please share your API method or postman collection to debug your API call